# Python NLTK - Preventing stop word removal from removing EVERY word

Tags: python, nltk

I'm working with very short strings of words, and a few of them are stupid. Hypothetically, I could have a string of "you an a" and if I remove stopwords, that string would be blank. Since I'm classifying in a loop, if it comes to a blank string it just stops with an error. I've created the following code to fix this:

```
def title_features(words):
filter_words = [word for word in words.split() if word not in stopwords.words('english')]
features={}
if len(filter_words) >= 1:
    features['First word'] = ''.join(filter_words[0])
else:
    features['First word'] = ''.join(words.split()[0])
return features
```

This ensures that I don't have the error, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it. Or a way to do it where it won't get rid of all the words, if they are all stopwords.

Comment: It sounds like stopword removal is not a good idea for your corpus...

Comment: Not all of them are like that.

I'm not sure if it's a good idea, but I'm going to test it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could re-write as:

```
def title_features(words):
    filtered = [word for word in words.split() if word not in stopwords.words('english')]
    return {'First word': (filtered or words.split(None, 1) or [''])[0]}
```

Which will take `filtered` if it's not empty (eg - has a length or one or more), or in the case it is empty, then proceeds to split the original, and in the case that's empty defaults to a one element list with an empty string. You than take the first element using `[0]` of whichever of those was chosen (the first non-stop word, the first word of the string or an empty string).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to check the result of filtering, and restore the full word list if necessary. Then the rest of your code can use a single variable without checks.

```
def title_features(words):
    filter_words = [word for word in words.split() if word not in stopwords.words('english')]
    if not filter_words:       # Use full list if necessary
        filter_words = words

    features={}
    features['First word'] = filter_words[0]
    features[...] = ...

    return features
```